# apt-get update stuck: Connecting to security.ubuntu.com

Tags: networking, apt, 15.04, ipv6

When I run `apt-get update` on my machine it gets stuck at:

```
100% [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::15)] [Connecting to archive.canonical.com (2001:67c:1360:8c01::16)]
```

I have made no recent changes to the system and use my home network which worked fine previously.

I can't explain why it switched to using IPv6.
I have IPv6 set to `ignore` for the wireless network:

[image]

Ouput of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: mlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 4c:0b:be:22:0a:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.2.106/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic mlan0
   valid_lft 1814086sec preferred_lft 1814086sec
inet6 ::d5:b551:28db:2789:225/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
   valid_lft 604483sec preferred_lft 85483sec
inet6 ::d5:4e0b:beff:fe22:ab4/64 scope global mngtmpaddr dynamic 
   valid_lft 604779sec preferred_lft 86379sec
inet6 fe80::4e0b:beff:fe22:ab4/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Change the IP addressing to IPv4 and then try again..

Comment: Why are you using IPv6? Like heemayl said, change to using IPv4, under Network Settings>[Adapter]>Advanced.

Comment: I don't know why it switched to IPv6. I added additional information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get apt-get stop using ipv6](http://askubuntu.com/questions/269557/get-apt-get-stop-using-ipv6)

Comment: It looks as if you may have a host sending router advertisements with `0:0:0:d5::/64`. This range is listed as reserved by IETF, so that is definitely not a valid prefix to be advertising. If those RAs have stopped already, it may be impossible to find out, where they came from. In that case all you can really do is to restart the network interface and the problem goes away. If the RAs are still being send, then you can look at a packet capture to see which MAC they are coming from.

Comment: Other than the misconfigured IPv6 connectivity, another contributor to your problem is the lack of RFC 6555 support in `apt-get`. Had `apt-get` followed RFC 6555, you would never have noticed any problem.

Comment: Your local router is doing something wrong, and giving you invalid IPv6 addresses. Check and fix the router's configuration.

Comment: Best solution to the problem found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/574569/apt-get-stuck-at-0-connecting-to-us-archive-ubuntu-com

Comment: For posterity... Thinking "I don't have any reason to use IPV6 yet" I deleted a firewall security definition (openstack) to allow IPV6 Egress. Oops. Recreating that rule (then cancelling and restarting the update) allowed the update to proceed as normal, with no changes to local config files. Note: In this example there was Not a problem with apt or with v4/v6 preferences. I suspect we'll see more of this as time goes on and v6 gets more use.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The IPv6 setting for the network were ignored, but disabling IPv6 via `/etc/sysctl.conf` worked:

Add the following lines at the bottom of `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Run `sudo sysctl -p` to reload  the `/etc/sysctl.conf` settings.

Comment: That's not how you should be doing. Those lines means once you connect to a network, which actually has IPv6, you'll get a less reliable connection than you were supposed to. Also, those lines do nothing to fix the root cause of your problem, which you haven't even identified.

Comment: I do not need IPv6 anywhere so this works just fine.

Comment: That's a common myth. Reality is that in a couple of months, Africa will be the only region of the world, which have not run out of IPv4 addresses.

Comment: Yes for non private ip adresses. But on small networks like my home network I wil always use IPv4.

Comment: That's just silly, because for connecting to hosts on the same network segment there are multiple advantages in IPv6 link-local addresses compared to IPv4.

Comment: That may be true but none of this advantages will be big enough to make me rember IPv6 adresses.

Comment: That's another myth. The only IPv6 addresses which are really relevant to remember are `::1` and `ff02::1`. All other addresses you get through DNS.

Comment: If you setup DNS. For my home computers, routers and all other devices tehre is no DNS. And I would think 99% of peapoile use IPx4 for private networks.

Comment: If you can't remember the IP of a device, you can just ping `ff02::1` and pick it from the list of devices that respond. That's easier than remembering even the IPv4 address of each device.

Comment: Can't do that from my phone ;) Lets just agree that we disagree.

Comment: Do what you want to do. I just comment to ensure that anybody else who might come across the same problem knows that making the suggested changes to `sysctl.conf` is going to cause problems eventually.

Answer (score 205):

This worked for me, courtesy of Zach Adams (https://zach-adams.com/2015/01/apt-get-cant-connect-to-security-ubuntu-fix/):

> Turns out this is an issue where
>   connecting over IPv6 on some servers causes them to get stuck at this
>   point. The fix is really simple.

Open **/etc/gai.conf**

Under the line

> ```
> # For sites which prefer IPv4 connections change the last line to
> ```

Uncomment the following line by removing the `#`:

> ```
> # precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100
> ```
>
> This will allow you to still use IPv6 but sets IPv4 as the precedence
>   so that apt-get won’t get stuck.

Comment: Thanks! This answer is much better than just slavishly disabling ipv6.

Comment: If you get no luck with this, try that: http://askubuntu.com/a/759540/4246

Comment: OMG that helped so much!

Comment: Note: This is still valid on 14.04 and 16.04 LTS versions

Comment: Worked for me on Linux Mint 18.1 & 18.2. This should be default.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.04 here, after waiting tons of minutes for the timeout. thanks!

Comment: This worked for me in ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Had to do it in Kubuntu 17.10... this default could be changed to solution above.

Comment: Your reply is the gift that just keeps on giving: thank you :)

Comment: Wow, this reduced my `apt-get update` from 12 minutes to under a second. Impressive.

Comment: Worked great for me -- don't forget to log off then back on to apply the change...

Comment: Worked great on Linux Mint 18.3. You don't need to log off to apply the change.

Comment: Awesome! This worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS! Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

A better approach is to use apt-get as follows instead of editing gai.conf file.

```
sudo apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update
```

If you want to make this persistent just add an alias for 'apt-get' in your bash file.

Comment: But wouldn't this make connections that could be IPv6 all IPv4?

Comment: @metame that's the whole point. OP said his IPv6 is disabled, and attempting to use it causes problems.

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions did not help ... in my case I created an aws ec2 instance Ubuntu 18.04  using

```
Auto-assign Public IP -> no pick disable
```

after trying all suggested solutions I threw up my hands and killed that and created a new ec2 instance using

```
Auto-assign Public IP -> yes  Use subnet setting (Enable)
```

and it worked fine ... `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` are happy now

Comment: for me it was the firewall issue. `allowing outbound connections` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

On WSL(Ubuntu) this can be caused by some Antivirus rule related to wsl, preventing outbound plain-http access.

Comment: didn't expect this. but worked for me 