# apt-get update hangs on a repo addr that should be responsive

Tags: apt, dns, repository

--DUPLICATES

[apt-get stuck at 0 [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574569/apt-get-stuck-at-0-connecting-to-us-archive-ubuntu-com)

--RESOLVED same as in link above...

general env ( a new isp 2 weeks ago 'web-pass.com' )
ubuntu 12.04
no local dns cache ( config entries count =0 )

problem

apt-get update is bad , hangs up at repo addr below ....

```
[Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::15)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (2001:67c:1562::15)
```

given the diagnostics from my system below , i dont understand the issue ( why is apt-get not seeing/connecting to a repo that should be reachable??

```
rob@ ~$ nmcli dev list iface eth0 | grep IP4

IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 100.65.108.17/23, gw = 100.65.108.1
IP4.DNS[1]:                             208.80.68.212
IP4.DNS[2]:                             204.14.152.2
IP4.DNS[3]:                             204.14.152.5
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          web-pass.com
```

so go get the repo from the first dns entry listed above...

```
rob@ ~$ dig -t a us.archive.ubuntu.com @208.80.68.212

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> -t a us.archive.ubuntu.com @208.80.68.212
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20474
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 4

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;us.archive.ubuntu.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  10  IN  A   91.189.91.24
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  10  IN  A   91.189.91.13
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  10  IN  A   91.189.91.14
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  10  IN  A   91.189.91.15
us.archive.ubuntu.com.  10  IN  A   91.189.91.23

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ubuntu.com.     3402    IN  NS  ns4.p27.dynect.net.
ubuntu.com.     3402    IN  NS  ns2.p27.dynect.net.
ubuntu.com.     3402    IN  NS  ns3.p27.dynect.net.
ubuntu.com.     3402    IN  NS  ns1.p27.dynect.net.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.p27.dynect.net. 2123    IN  A   208.78.70.27
ns2.p27.dynect.net. 2095    IN  A   204.13.250.27
ns3.p27.dynect.net. 2095    IN  A   208.78.71.27
ns4.p27.dynect.net. 2123    IN  A   204.13.251.27
```

why the issue on connecting to the ubuntu repo when it shows up fine on a 'dig' issued to the first dns entry from 'ns_n.webpass.net' ??

Ive assumed  IPv4 in the above (noobie on IP6)... this may be my problem.

ifconfig for eth0 below seems to indicate IP6...

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:03:9a:b5:d2:1c  
          inet addr:100.65.108.17  Bcast:100.65.109.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: 2604:5500:f:69:ea03:9aff:feb5:d21c/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::ea03:9aff:feb5:d21c/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2604:5500:f:69:f946:f08:1a94:4a23/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:617023 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:313902 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:657715484 (657.7 MB)  TX bytes:68766408 (68.7 MB)
```

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/a/620467/158442

Comment: Have you tried to change the server location?

Comment: no. All i did is 'ifdown' then 'ifup' on all interfaces .. then retry apt-get update ... no change - still hangs up.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method  did not do anything using accepted answer

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
sudo -i
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

and then enter update manager, and fix broken package, and it might work fine this way.

Comment: The OP (if you read the top) has already found an answer at a posted link

Comment: You have 475 rep. You should know that questions and words such as "might" and "maybe" do not belong in answers.