# apt-get stuck at 0 [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com] in ububtu 16.04.4

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates

I want install various software on Ubuntu.
 I get stuck here, when I do:

```
sudo apt-get update

0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.152)] [Connecting to archive.canonical.com (91.189.92.191)] [Connecting to security.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.162)]
```

I have tried this help, but still no answer,

[apt-get stuck at 0 [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574569/apt-get-stuck-at-0-connecting-to-us-archive-ubuntu-com?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[apt-get update stuck: Connecting to security.ubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620317/apt-get-update-stuck-connecting-to-security-ubuntu-com/787491#787491)

Answer (score 1):

For me it was getting stuck at in.archive.ubuntu.com . I tried forcing IPV4 but this didn't work.

> sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true

It seems India server was down for sometime . I tried the following on Ubuntu 20.04 and this worked like a charm.

> software & updates -> ubuntu software -> Download From -> Select Main
> server instead of India server or which ever works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://medium.com/@muhammadtriwibowo/fix-apt-get-update-stuck-connecting-to-security-ubuntu-com-2471aa425d83) . 
The solutions above relate to a common ipv6 related issue. If it still doesn't work can you provide the exact error msg. I have tried & that solution worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Its just the firewall**. Just **disable** firewall in the **console**.

Run this:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

And your problem should be solved