# Timeout while Connecting archive.ubuntu.com and security.ubuntu.com while Building A Snap

Tags: networking, snap

I have a snapcraft.yaml as below:

```yaml
name: tgcli
version: git
summary: A Telegram Terminal Application
description: |
  `tgcli` is a terminal application to send
  message with bots on Telegram.

base: core18
confinement: devmode

parts:
  tgcli:
    plugin: rust
    source: .

apps:
  tgcli:
    command: bin/tgcli
```

I’m trying to build a Rust terminal application. I am [here](https://snapcraft.io/docs/rust-applications#:%7E:text=After%20you%E2%80%99ve%20created%20the%20snapcraft.yaml%2C%20you%20can%20build%20the%20snap%20by%20simply%20executing%20the%20snapcraft%20command%20in%20the%20project%20directory%3A) in the documentation. I run snapcraft. It tries to connect archive.ubuntu.com and security.ubuntu.com, yet fails to do so after a couple of minutes. The full output is:

```
Launching a container.
Build environment is in unknown state, cleaning first.
Waiting for container to be ready
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.network1.service → /lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.
Waiting for network to be ready...
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                    
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                          
  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                   
  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done                                 
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::18). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1562::15). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.39), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out Could not connect to security.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.91.38), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::23). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.142), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package udev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  systemd

E: Unable to locate package dirmngr
E: Package 'udev' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package fuse
An error occurred when trying to execute 'apt-get install dirmngr udev fuse --yes' with 'LXD': returned exit code 100.
```

I have tried to solve it, I have seen solutions like in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620317/apt-get-update-stuck-connecting-to-security-ubuntu-com) one, yet it does not work. I think it’s because snaps work in a confined environment.

I also tried removing lxd and rebuilding my snap so that it reinstalls and reconfigures lxd but that didn't work either.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Timeouts usually mean your network is blocking the connections, I can confirm those IPs are visible and reachable currently from different country exfil points.  Is there some type of network rules on your network that control access to the Internet directly?

Comment: so, i just checked it out. the issue seems like it. i removed `ufw`, ran `snapcraft` again. but this time, i get `Waiting for network to be ready...` for around two minutes, then `Failed to setup networking.`, which fails installing `udev`. let me investigate it more.

Comment: Nope, this time `lxc` fails to set up networking as above. I ran out of options.